# How does onTap VoidCallback handler work when it's an async (returning a Future<Null>)?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to push a route to display a ListView item when that item is tapped (`onTap`). The `onTap` property for `InkWell` is defined as a `VoidCallback`. However, I would like to be able to receive a return value from the callback, indicating whether the user has modified said item in the dialog that was opened.

Assigning a `Future<Null> async` function to `onTap` seems to be OK, as per the Shrine Demo (`shrine_home.dart` in the flutter_gallery example):

```
  Future<Null> _showOrderPage(Product product) async {
    final Order order = _shoppingCart[product] ?? new Order(product: product);
    final Order completedOrder = await Navigator.push(context, new ShrineOrderRoute(
      order: order,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return new OrderPage(
          order: order,
          products: _products,
          shoppingCart: _shoppingCart,
        );
      }
    ));
    assert(completedOrder.product != null);
    if (completedOrder.quantity == 0)
      _shoppingCart.remove(completedOrder.product);
  }
```

Why and how is this working? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart allows you to use a function with a non-void return value as a function with a void return value. The function will still return values as normal, but the analyzer will infer that they're of the void type and will complain if you try to use them, unless you cast them back to something else.

```
typedef void VoidCallback();
typedef int IntCallback();

final IntCallback i = () => 42;

void main() {
  final VoidCallback v = i;
  print("${v()}");        // prints 42
  print(v() as int);      // also prints 42
  print(v().toString());  // also prints 42, but analyzer complains:
                          // method 'toString' isn't defined for class 'void'
}
```

That is why you can use a function that returns a `Future<Null>` as a `VoidCallback`.

Comment: Ah, much clearer now. (Only picked up Dart & Flutter around 2 weeks ago, so please pardon the newbie questions.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oops. Just realized the assignment was actually via a lambda, which is a `VoidCallback`:

```
onPressed: () { _showOrderPage(product); }
```

Still - it seems to be working for me in another place, where I assign a `Future<Null> async` function to the `onPressed` method of `FloatingActionButton`...