# Flutter: How to detect Async code in a UI Callback

Tags: flutter

I have a button which when pressed calls an async job. This job usually is nearly instant but under certain conditions in may take a bit longer. (Eg - saving a file)

```dart
RaisedButton(
  child: Text("Next Page"),
  onPressed: () async {
    await shouldOnlyBeExecutedOnce();
  }),
),
```

Depending on how long the asyncTask takes, the user can press the button again, and call the callback again.

I see no way of fixing this apart from being aware that calling async code in a sync callback should update the UI to show that it is processing, and modify the UI to make sure the user cannot press it again.

This seems cumbersome.

Am I missing something or is there a better way? I would ideally like to forbid giving an async function when expecting sync function. In the case of `onPressed` its signature is `VoidCallback`, which accepts [any return value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44621239/147435). Is there some lint to enforce the method to always return void?

Now that I'm aware of it, I find this problem in many places. Do other people also encounter a similar problem? Or maybe my web searching skills aren't good and I've missed this in the documentation.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can we show loading indicator / process indicator while calling funucation?

Comment: disable button or show big loading indicator other the screen so user can't do anything

Comment: @PrajapatiAmit: Yup. Both your solutions would work. My question is more about how to detect such cases in an existing code base, and a less cumbersome way to fix this - such as just wrapping my widget in another which handles this. It seems like a problem everyone would be encountering.

Answer (score 0):

I have had same thing, and made a work-around for it
I created a bool flag at the top of my class

```
bool isProcessing = false;
```

and in onPressed I did something like this:

```
onPressed: isProcessing ? null : () async {
   isProcessing = true;
   setState(() {});
   await someAsyncTask();
   isProcessing = false;
   setState(() {});
}
```

If you want to handle your widget inside something that handles the future returned from your method

You can use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Just wrap your widget inside FutureBuilder and give it your function as future and you'll get in what state exactly your async function is.